# Es posible crear un archivo de excel a partir de una lista y luego adjuntar y enviar por correo electrónico?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Espero que se encuentren muy bien.

Cabe mencionar que apenas estoy adentrandome en asp .net c# , tengo una lista de este tipo  var datosRM = new List(); donde tengo información de una base de datos.

Tengo una aplicación de consola con su biblioteca de clases donde en esta ultima tengo el envio de correo electrónico, mi duda es si es posible
crear un archivo de excel a partir de una lista y luego adjuntar y enviar por correo electrónico ?

Este es el método con el que realizo el envio de correo donde solo le paso los parámetros de correo de destino, asunto y mensaje del correo donde aquí le paso la lista en una tabla html:

```
public string EnviarCorreo(string correoDestino, string asunto, string mensajeCorreo)
```

{
string mensaje = "Error al enviar correo";

```
try
{
    string Host = "test.correo.mx";
    int Puerto = 587;
    string Usuario = "test@correo.mx";
    string Clave = "cskjasFRQWQY-OQUIWH788";//clave generada para aplicación en GMAIL

    //Proporcionamos autenticacion de gmail
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Host, Puerto);
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

    //Se separan los correos de destino
    string[] Destinatario = correoDestino.Split(',');
    foreach (string correo in Destinatario) if (correo != "") msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(correo));// si es mas de uno los agrega

    msg.From = new MailAddress(Usuario, "CORREO DE CONCILIACIÓN DE LA RED MAS");
    // msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(correoDestino));

    msg.Subject = asunto;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = mensajeCorreo;

    //ENVIAMOS EL CORREO
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Usuario, Clave);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(msg);
    //MessageBox.Show("Mensaje Enviado!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error al enviar correo " + ex.Message);
}
return mensaje;
```

}

Comment: Supongo que tu pregunta no es "Si es posible? (que lo es)" es más el "Como hacerlo?" . Debes especificar cual es la parte que te está dando problema, adjuntar el archivo?? crear el excel?? Si es esto último, debes ocupar una libreria, te recomiendo EPPlus a mí me ha dado buenos resultados

Comment: Entiendo gracias por la corrección, si lo pensé pero quería tener la certeza de que si es posible ya que si he visto la parte de la creación y la del envió pero por aparte, gracias por la referencia EPPlus  lo investigare.